# Brightness button (Fn + F5/F6) does not work after installing Kubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, kubuntu

I installed the Kubuntu 11.10 on my laptop and now the brightness keys do not work. Before I was using Debian and they functioned normally. Could someone tell me if the problem is it just me or is the problem with this version of Kubuntu?
How to make it work again?

Answer (score 1):

Go to System Settings>Power Management> Power Profiles and set the brightness for the Performance profile.
That should be the one your laptop uses when it's plugged in.

You can also install a widget to adjust it. Click on the Panel Tool Box icon (far right of bottom taskbar)> Add Widgets> Get New Widgets> Download New Plasma Widgets and do a search from there.

Answer (score 0):

Go to System > Preferences > Keyboard shortcuts.

You should be able to set the brightness shortcuts yourself.

Comment: I've done it but still does not change ... Sometimes it is so clear I can not even look, because sometimes it gets so dark that not even see a thing ...